# Are neutrons polarized by the electric field of protons inside a heavy nucleus making the nucleus more 'positive'?

Tags: electric-fields, nuclear-physics, dielectric, dipole-moment

Are neutrons polarized by the electric field of protons inside a heavy nucleus of an atom making the nucleus more positive for the electrons? I think a spherical capacitor with unchanging amount of free charge increases its field if a dielectric is placed inside it so why should not the nucleus of a heavy atom act simmilarly where the neutrons behave as the dielectric behaves inside the capacitor.... or maybe protons and neutrons in the nucleus are so arranged that there is no net force towards neutrons but the field vectors that act on neutrons point in all directions although the field is radial outside the nucleus surface?

Comment: Do neutrons have electric charge? How they can be polarized if they have no electric charge? How can fundamental particles be polarized?

Comment: Neutrons aren't fundamental particles, they're hadrons made up of quarks which do have a charge

Answer (score 3):

Free neutrons in s[trong electric fields](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168900289902672)

> In a strong electric field, the neutron, due to its internal charge structure, acquires an induced electric dipole moment. For the electric polarizability of the neutron a value of  $ α_n~ 1x10^{-3} fm^3$ , similar to that of the proton, is expected from quark model calculations

...

> In the strong electric field near the surface of heavy nuclei, effects due to the electric polarizability of the neutron contribute up to 1% of the total neutron-atom scattering

So the fact that the neutron is a composite of charged quarks leads to a measurable polarization effect, but not, as you seem to imply changes in charge. Charge is a conserved quantum number.

Comment: Can this be compared?...protons inside the nucleus with free charge of a spherical capacitor and neutrons inside the nucleus with extra charge produced by the 'neutral' dielectric that is excited by the el. field....I think that a spherical capacitor with free charge Q should produce a more intense field after the  insertion of a dielectric? ...or I am wrong?

Comment: The neutrons are already electric dipoles even without a electric field to polarise them.

Comment: @JankoBradvica:  A dielectric only enhances the electric field due to a free charge at points inside the dielectric. If neurons are acting as a dielectric, we might except them to enhance the protons’ electric field inside the nucleus, but not outside the nucleus. And of course, electrons are very unlikely to be found in the nucleus.